# how to run foreach loop with ternary condition

Tags: php, loops, foreach

i have two foreach loop to display some data, 
but i want to use a single foreach on basis of database result.

means if there is any row  returns from database then 
`forach($first as $fk=>$fv)` should execute otherwise 
`foreach($other as $ok)` should execute.
i m unsing below ternary operator which gives parse error

```
$n=$db->numRows($taskData); // databsse results

<?php ($n) ? foreach ($first as $fk=>$fv) : foreach ($other as $ok) 
{ ?>
<table><tr><td>......some data...</td></tr></table>
<?php } ?>
```

please suggest me how to handle such condition via ternary operator or any other idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the conditional operator to select the array to use and then use `$fv` as the value rather than `$ok` for the second option.

```
foreach ( ($n ? $first : $other) as $fk => $fv )
```

Having two totally different loops being selected by a condition and with totally different variables would not really be a good idea as it would lead to really confusing code as you wouldn't be sure without checking `$n` which of `$fk`, `$fv` and `$ok` were set.

If you do need to do something different depending on the condition maybe the sections of code that are the same into functions would be a better idea?

Comment: second array is numeric array whether first array is associative array whose key is idnetical to second array value
thats y i use `$ok` only

Comment: It doesn't really matter - you can use `$key => $val` syntax on numerical arrays as well.

Comment: i used `array_flip` for the other array now both array's key are used in foreach

Comment: I think, this is "ternary operator inside foreach", not "foreach inside ternary operator" as the original question asked...